# DS1307 12 hours mode

Tags: i2c, rtc

I'm trying to configure a DS1307 RTC to be in 12-hours mode.
I've double and triple check my settings, and cannot understand what I have wrong.

According to the documentation, bit 6 of register 0x02 should be high to enable 12 hour mode.
In 12 hours mode, bit 5 of register 0x02 will be high on PM, and low on AM.

I've correctly enabled the 12 hour mode in the register.
But when dumping the content of hour register 0x02 without any modification, I got the following value when transitioning from 11h59m59s AM to the next second: 0x52 -> 0x41.

On those two value, I have the bit 6 high, so I am in 12 hour mode. I also have a correct transition from a value of 12 hour to 1 hour. But the AM/PM bit don't change from AM to PM.

What did I miss here ? I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your hours register values of 0x52->0x41 are correct but for transitioning from 12.xxAM to 1.xxAM.

The register 0x02 layout is:

`3:0  Hours low digit
    4   12hr: 0=AM, 1=PM   24hr: 10's digit
    5   10's digit
    6   Mode: 0=24hr; 1=12hr
    7   Always 0`

Breaking down your values...

0x52 is 0101 0010 and means "12 hr mode, 10+2 o'clock AM".

0x41 is 0100 0001 and means "12 hr mode, 1 o'clock AM".

So it looks like the fault is in your AM-PM rollover test program.

You're actually testing for 12.59AM->1.00AM, not the 11.59AM->12.00PM you think you're trying.

Comment: @user27512, how did you fix it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is no rollover from 12:59 pm to 13:00 (1 pm). The rollover occurs from 11:59 to 12:00.

The results seem consistent with reality.